# MongoDB Projection Performance - or just many small documents?

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, projection, query-performance

I'm building a collection for User Settings / Preferences and other user related stuff.

At the moment a document look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "USER_ID",
  "setting1": { "foo": "bar" },
  "setting2": true,
  "setting3": "this might be a huuuuge email template",
  ...
}
```

And I query stuff by the user's id and then I use a projection to get the settings I need, i.e.:

```
find( {"_id":"USER_ID"} , {"setting2":1, "setting3":1} )
```

What if such a document will grow to 5 MB and has 500 keys? Will this still perform well?

Or should I use a document per USER_ID-SettingsKey-Tuple? (With index on `user` and `key`) i.e.:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("..."),
  "user": "USER_ID",
  "key": "setting1",
  "value": { "foo": "bar" }
}
{
  "_id":ObjectId("..."),
  "user": "USER_ID",
  "key": "setting2",
  "value": true
}
...
```

And then query with `find({user:"USER_ID", key:{$in:[setting1, setting2]}})`

What will perform better for many (and huge) settings per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting is better. fewer documents = higher performance.
For the best performance, I'd break your settings into 22 categories with 22 keys in each, that way accessing one property would take a maximum of `22+22=44` steps instead of 500. Of course, only break them into sensible groups, if at all.

*insert stupid quote about premature optimization here*

Comment: yeah, I actually did not ran into performance issues, because the test setup has only 20 users with 50 settings each. **but** if I can now make things right with 1 hour of effort, I don't have to bang my head in a few month and then have to convert thousands of documents, etc. `;)`. The main reason for this question was: Maybe it's getting really slow to find a key within a document, and so projection gets really slow.

Comment: It's not finding the key within the document that will be slow, it's doing all of the I/O to load a whole document in memory when part of it is needed. I would default to your first, most logical document structure and see how your memory/disk usage behavior is later.